# Prevent ResourcePropertySource from throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring

Is there a way to prevent `ResourcePropertySource` from throwing `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="propertySources">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource">
                <constructor-arg value="file:#{systemProperties['user.home']}/user.properties"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource">
                <constructor-arg value="classpath:project.properties"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'd like t to fallback to the `project.properties` if the `user.properties` file if not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complex.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${user.home}/user.properties,classpath:project.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

That should be all you need. No need for EL or directly use a `ResourcePropertySource`.